# Find and label the candles with higher values than the candle since last condition in pine script

Tags: pine-script

how can I find and label the candles with higher values than the high value of the candle since last condition (not all conditions)? I the image attachment, I want to label the candles which have higher value above the blue line since the condition point (blue square and white down arrow).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `high` price using a `var` variable whenever your condition is `true`.

Then compare the current price with that variable.

```
var float high_at_cond = na
high_at_cond := your_cond ? high : high_at_cond // If your condition is true, get the high price. Keep the old value otherwise
is_higher = (high > high_at_cond)
```